# JAX-RS consume JSON and read it with javax.json

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

How to consume json from post and read it with javax.json

how to do it without add more depencies or relate json to entity bean

**json (application/json)**

```
{"employees":[
   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
   {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

**server**

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String receiveJSON( whatShouldIput data ){

      JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(data );
      JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
      JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("data");
      for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
          System.out.print(result.getJsonObject("employees").getString("firstName"));
          System.out.print(" ");
          System.out.println(result.getString("lastName", ""));
          System.out.println("-----------");
     }

        return "ok";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily using `Apache CXF API`. You have to provide json provider that will convert your json data to Object directly. `Ideally, we should not write marshalling or unmarshalling code service implementation.`

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html

or If you want to unmarshal json data, use `ObjectMapper` of `jackson framework`

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 0):

"whatShouldIput" should be type "String".  A couple of other tweaks are needed.  Here is a sample program that uses your input.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "{\"employees\":["
            + "{\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},"
            + "{\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"},"
            + "{\"firstName\":\"Peter\", \"lastName\":\"Jones\"}" + "]}";
    System.out.println(receiveJSON(input));
}

public static String receiveJSON(String data) {

    try (StringReader sReader = new StringReader(data);
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(sReader)) {
        JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
        JsonArray results = obj.getJsonArray("employees");
        for (JsonObject result : results.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)) {
            System.out.print(result.getString("firstName"));
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(result.getString("lastName", ""));
            System.out.println("-----------");
        }
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John Doe
-----------
Anna Smith
-----------
Peter Jones
-----------
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on Jersey, just declare it as a JsonObject:

```
public String receiveJSON( JsonObject data )
```

It will automatically get parsed for you

See also https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p for setting up dependencies